# Odd partitions using last_day

Tags: oracle, date, partitioning

Hi lads
I'm trying to automatize a partitioning process here, and well ren into something odd.
Why wouldnt'the following work?

```
create table flp_aa (cdate date, value varchar2(255))
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64M
           )
LOGGING
PARTITION BY RANGE (cdate)
(  
  PARTITION flp_aa_1010 VALUES LESS THAN (last_day(to_date('20101101', 'YYYYMMDD')))
    NOLOGGING
    NOCOMPRESS
    PCTFREE    10
    INITRANS   1
    MAXTRANS   255
    STORAGE    (
                INITIAL          64M
                NEXT             512K
                MINEXTENTS       1
                MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                PCTINCREASE      0
                BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                )
)
```

The idea is to use `last_day(to_date('20101101', 'YYYYMMDD'))` so each pretty partition ends on the last day of that month and everybody is happy. However I get an [ORA-14019](http://ora-14019.ora-code.com/) when trying to execute that code...

**[UPDATE]**

Darn odd:

This **work**:

```
  (...)
  PARTITION flp_aa_1010 VALUES LESS THAN (to_date('20101101', 'YYYYMMDD'))
  (...)
```

This doesn't work:

```
  (...)
  PARTITION flp_aa_1010 VALUES LESS THAN (last_day(to_date('20101101', 'YYYYMMDD')))
  (...)
```

And this **does not again**:

```
  (...)
  PPARTITION flp_aa_1010 VALUES LESS THAN to_date(last_day(to_date('201010','YYYYMM'))))
  (...)
```

*What the duck? which class did I miss here?*
Isn't the output of all these functions the same?

could anyone enlighten me?

cheers

f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the link you posted says:

> partition bound element must be one
>   of: string, datetime or interval
>   literal, number, or MAXVALUE

A function call (LAST_DAY) is not a string, datetime or interval
literal, number, or MAXVALUE. True, TO_DATE is a function call, but this is allowed as an exception because traditionally it was the only way to generate a DATE literal (you can now use the ANSI format DATE '2010-11-26' but not a lot of people know that).  See [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm#sthref7435).

However, at the point where you generate the value '20101101', you could apply LAST_DAY and use the result instead of that - something like:

```
'... VALUES LESS THAN (' || TO_CHAR (LAST_DAY (...), 'YYYYMMDD') || ')...'
```

Comment: Well.. not quite. I had tried that before. Dosen't seem to be the case. You see, the field `cdate` is of date type. if you simply do `... VALUES LESS THAN (to_date('20101101', 'YYYYMMDD')) ...` it works! Still, I have tried also to convert my cdate into string and use the to_char and it would not work when placing the "last_day" thing... odd...

Comment: I have updated my answer.  TO_DATE('20101101', 'YYYYMMDD') is considered to be a date literal, whereas LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('20101101', 'YYYYMMDD')) is not.